# Fetch file to multer returns undefined

Tags: fetch, postman, multer

I want to fetch a file via JS to multer but it always returns undefined. I made a postman request and works perfectly and the file saves in '/uploads'. Tried to look into my JS code but don't know whats wrong.

HTML:

```html
<form action="/" class="form" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return(validate())">
    <div class="form__div">
        <label class="form__label" for="image">Send an image (optional)</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    </div>
    <button class="form__submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
const validate = () => {
    const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form'));

    fetch('/send_file', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData.get('image') 
    }) 
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return false;
}
```

Node:

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.listen(3000);

app.post('/send_file', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.image);
    res.end();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to send data using multer, you must put this in your form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```